# Jquery left and right mouse button listenier

Tags: jquery, button, click, mouse, listener

I am listening for the right mouse click with the following code:

```
$.contextMenu({

     selector: '.context-menu-one', 
     callback: function(key, options){

     // labels for the right click options
     items:{
          "green": {name: "Option 1", icon: "edit"},
          "amber": {name: "Option 2", icon: "cut"},
      "red": {name: "Optino 3", icon: "cut"},
          "grey": {name: "Optino 4", icon: "copy"}
     }

});
```

Then my div is as follows:

```
<div class="cell">
 <div class="context-menu-one">An option</div>
</div>
```

This works well but I have noticed that users devices which are touch screen driven or single mouse button will find it hard to quickly right click (or equivalent), so my question is how difficult would it be to switch the listener to the left or single mouse click equivalent?

Thanks,

Alan

Answer (score 0):

Apologies, I just realised that there is more code to this:

jquery.contextMenu.js

The documentation states that to use the left button slector the following is required:

```
selector: '.context-menu-one', 
trigger: 'left',
callback: function(key, options){....
```

Hopefully this may help someone who is looking switch the button selector around.

Alan.